# Robots suscriptores a Newsletter Mailchimp

Tags: php, html, formularios

utilizo mailchimp para para implementar un formulario en mis webs para hacer newsletters.

Estos últimos días he recibido muchos mensajes de usuarios falsos (robots) que se han suscrito a mi newsletter. Para evitar esto he utilizado la opción reCAPTCHA para mejorar la seguridad de mi formulario, Pero tampoco ha dado resultado, siguen suscribiéndose robots a mis newsletter.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar esto? no sé qué más puedo hacer.

Comment: ¿Has intentado hablar con los de [Soporte de MailChimp](http://kb.mailchimp.com/es/accounts/management/mailchimp-support-options)?

Comment: Sí, mi cliente recibe email de este tipo:    Registrado un nuevo usuario en tu sitio Nombre del Sitio*:

Nombre de usuario: lizbrodie8836

Correo electrónico: lizbrodie@yahoo.co.uk
He instalado un plugin que incluye reCapcha en el formulario de registro de wordpress, a ver si da solucion al problema ¿voy bien encaminado o se refiere a otra cosa los mensaje que recibe?